# "Merging" Multiple Database Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

*I've read through multiple questions here on SO regarding merging multiple databases into one, however they primarily all deal with uniform schema/tables.  My apologies if I'm repeating a question.*

I have an assortment of database tables that are all similar, but not identical.  For example, imagine ten databases with ten "User" tables.  All contain a `userid` (we'll use this for reference).  Most contain `username` and an `email` columns.  Some will contain other columns, such as `skype`, `msn`, `phone`, etc. that exist in only a few of the other tables, or no other tables.

I want to merge this content into one database, with the prerequisite that, moving forward, the possibility of additional databases also containing unique columns will also need to be merged into the new database.

I've been looking at EAV Tables, and was considering something along the lines of (continuing with the example above) a master user table that had a newly-assigned user id (`id`), originating database reference of some type (`database_id`), and the originating user-id (`native_user_id`).  I'd then have a separate properties table with a primary key (`id`), a entity key (`user_id`), an attribute (`attribute`) column, and the value (`value`) column.

The issue at hand is that almost everything I've read recommends against EAV tables while implying there are better ways to go about this.  However, I've not actually found any material that covers what this method would be.

So, my questions:

1. Are EAV Tables really *that* bad?
2. What practical major downfalls that I should plan ahead for should I go the EAV table route (any examples of personal experience would be swell)?
3. What alternatives exist for handling this type of scenario besides EAV tables (while accommodating future attributes without tedious ALTER TABLE commands)?

Comment: Does it have to be a SQL solution or is looking at some NoSQL databases an option?

Comment: if you have arbitrary "width" data sets, then an EAV is a simple way of representing it. you're unpivoting data and turning multiple columns in a smaller fixed set of columns. much easier to deal with. but if your db doesn't directly support pivot queries, it's much harder going the other way from the small-fixed-columns to many-arbitrary-columns

Comment: Also keep in mind that you will be mucking up your data types. Since you will be storing all data as string (as opposed to int,double,etc...) so sorting, and querying has to be altered

Comment: @Matt I'm completely unfamiliar with NoSQL, and even how much its data storage differs from SQL.  Time wise, I wouldn't be super comfortable opting for that route.  Would NoSQL handle this scenario better than SQL?

Comment: Can you provide additional schema information for the tables you are merging.  Also, are you using the IDs for these tables for anything significant?  The most maintainable I think would be to create a script to throw all those tables into a new table line by line, updating what needs to be updated, then it is done once and you can remove the old tables, but that can have problems if there are duplicate IDs that are used elsewhere

Comment: @MarshallTigerus No, I can't offer more information on the schema for the tables because each table has the potential to vary from any other, hence the purpose of the question.  Doing it line-by-line doesn't address the issue of new attributes popping up in the future.

Comment: @Rejected so the plan is to keep the multiple distinct tables?  Or are you saying there will be more tables in the future to merge in?

Comment: @MarshallTigerus No.  The plan is to have all relevant data migrated to a single location.

Comment: @Rejected I don't see the problem then.  You build a script to move all the data into one table, then if you later need a new column, you alter that table.  One table

Comment: @MarshallTigerus The problem is that constantly altering the table to add new columns is a slow process that likely involve a bunch of downtime which I'd rather avoid. I have no way of pre-planning for what columns may be needed.

Comment: @Rejected glad I don't have to work on that project.

Answer (score 1):

I used EAV in a project to address requirements similar to yours: lack of a universal data model in the messy real world.

In my case, EAV allowed incremental change as the company grew by acquisition, which in turn caused continual expansion, refinement, or generalization of the data model.  The project ultimately failed because management withdrew support for it.

I learned that EAV presents itself to management and users as needlessly complex unless you do the work to create concise views to hide the complexity while preserving the completeness of the data.  I also learned that EAV imposes a demand to fill in the "missing answers" in a meaningful way.  It isn't enough to say that every answer to a question that wasn't asked in database X is "NULL".  Sometimes that is not the right answer. "NULL" becomes a synonym for "I don't know; the attribute didn't exist in this database so no-one ever decided what the value should be".

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly broad question, eh?

If you have your tables already in SQL I suggest you try experimenting with this sort of UNION ALL query.

```
 SELECT 'one' AS dbid, 
        id AS id, 
        first AS first_name, 
        last AS last_name 
   FROM first_table
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'two' AS dbid, 
        member_id AS id, 
        fname AS first_name, 
        lname AS last_name 
   FROM members
```

Etcetera.  The idea is to use a UNION ALL query to try to coerce your various sources of information into a single result set, and figure out which of your values from those various sources are somehow conformable.  If the lion's share of your data is conformable -- that is, you can simply move it over into appropriate columns in your new tables, you'll avoid the worst pitfalls of EAV storage.

Once you have done that, you can use EAV style storage for your remaining information.

I hope this helps you plan this migration a bit.